# Editing a question to change links to inline images

Tags: discussion

I understand that you need a [certain amount of rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173120/needing-a-10-reputation-to-post-an-image) to include an image in a question.

When reviewing 'First-Posts' and I see a question/answer with images as links, is it OK to edit the post and add in the images as in-line ones? Obviously only after checking the image is OK first..!

Here's an [example question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23324867/2). The only issue I have with these images, are that they are rather large. I could download them, resize them and then repost them, but that seems too much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is definitely good to edit the question to bring the image in the question itself rather than just a link of the image.

On the issues of large images, don't worry about it. Stack Overflow is good at handling them and displaying them correctly.

Comment: If it was appropriate to use an image at all, sure. Quite often, it isn't. And if the image contains text, it's nearly always inappropriate.

Answer (score 19):

About the large images, you can access to thumbnails by adding `s`, `m` or `l` before the extension of the file (only if the image is hosted on imgur).

For example:

- original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dOo3.png
- small image: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dOo3`s`.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dOo3s.png)
- medium image: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dOo3`m`.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dOom.png)
- large image: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dOo3`l`.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dOo3l.png)

Thanks to Brock Adams for [pointing it out](https://stackapps.com/a/4652/24266).

There are also `b` (big square crop) and `h` (huge), see [this answer on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108821/237701) for examples with details.

Additionally, if you want to display the thumbnail of image linking to the original image, you have to use this syntax:

```
[![alt text][1]][2]

  [1]: Thumbnail URL
  [2]: Linked image URL
```

For example:

```
[![alt text][1]][2]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dOo3m.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dOo3.png
```

Gives this:

> [image]

I took this code from [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2191/237701)