# When is an image appropriate to be changed from a linked image to inline image?

Tags: discussion, edits

I have read the answer to this question.

[Editing a question to change links to inline images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252370/editing-a-question-to-change-links-to-inline-images).

In the accepted answer in seems that the answer is **always** as long as image OK. (I will change the term OK to **appropriate**)

*When is an image **appropriate** to be changed from linked image to inline image?*

- It is not a beautiful lady.
- It do not contain only text.
- It is of fundamental significance to understand the question

Would like some further guidelines, comments to unify my edit behavior with others.

This is an example of an edit I did (primarily because a comment stated that he could not see image and the image was fundamental to answer question, its a stack trace image). The edit did not feel right and lead me to post this question.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/10739858

**Possible solutions** (ignoring the fact that question maybe should be closed)

1. Edit to put in text relevant part of stack trace (3 line), keep image in link
2. Include image in-line (and notify user he should put text not image)

I choose solution 2, since I'm lazy but with some guidance I can conform to 1.

**NOTE:** I have edit the post after the comments made by @Patrice and @Deduplicator, considering them but in some case invalidating them.

Comment: I THINK that the reason why "appropriate" is used instead of important, is that when I inline a linked image, I do so just because I recognize the OP wanted it in his post, but couldn't do it himself. So all I'm doing is checking if it SHOULD have been in the post, then add it. That's just my 2 cents though

Comment: @Patrice: Even if the OP wanted to include it, quite often they *shouldn't even have tried*, block or no block: If the image contains text, it's nearly always inappropriate to use an image.

Comment: @Deduplicator indeed. which is what I consider "inappropriate" images. What I meant is (I may have been more unclear than what I meant there) if the image is remotely correct for the post (not blatantly incorrect, like the example you bring up), then I edit it in. If I see a need to then comment to the user about what should be used INSTEAD, or how to better his question, then I do. But the image itself, if it's not actively harmful or blatantly incorrect, I don't mind putting it, even if I end up suggesting to remove it. If only to help show new users how the site works.

Comment: @Deduplicator, made an edit to my post considering your comment, would like your advise?

Comment: Well, that's a clear-cut case: The image is pure text, and thus using an image is inexcusable. You can manually transcribe it if you want (or at least the relevant parts) and remove the link, certainly should comment to the OP, but *should not* inline it ever.

Comment: @Deduplicator, then I had the right feeling..... there is some rules, you can't be lazy like that!